# Javascript: Sharing a function between files

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

fileA.js

```
function addEvent(param1, param2) => {
  // do something
})

model.exports = function aFunctionThatUsesAddEvent(param1, param2) {
      addEvent(param1, param2) // This works fine.  
})
```

fileB.js

```
const FileA = require(__dirname + '/..fileA');

function letsAddEvent(param1, param2) {
     FileA.addEvent(param1, param2) {
       // I get an error: FileA.addEvent is not a function
     })
})
```

I have tried to use

```
model.exports = function addEvent(param1, param2) => {})
```

But then `aFunctionThatUsesAddEvent` can't call `addEvent(param1, param2)`

How do I declare a function that can be used locally and also used by another file?

Comment: Whats this suppose to mean `'/..fileA'`? Also, `addEvent` is not exposed and so its a privarte function. Try `export { addEvent: addEnent }` instead

Comment: It’s a path to access that file

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct. Shoudn't it be `../fileA`.  Secondly you are exporting `aFunctionThatUsesAddEvent ` and not `addEvent `. Invoke that from fileB

Comment: `FileA` ( in fileB.js) is `function aFunctionThatUsesAddEvent(param1, param2) {}`

Comment: Do you mean for `model.exports = xxx` to be `module.exports = xxx`?

Comment: You aren't exporting `addEvent` so it is not available outside the module in which it is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are exporting `function aFunctionThatUsesAddEvent` from `fileA.js`.

So, when you call `const FileA = require(__dirname + '/..fileA');` in `fileB.js`, `FileA` becomes `function aFunctionThatUsesAddEvent` and `FileA` doesn't have any `addEvent`.

There are multiple solutions to this problem.

Simplest One:

**fileA.js**

```
function addEvent(param1, param2) => {
  // do something
})

function aFunctionThatUsesAddEvent(param1, param2) {
    addEvent(param1, param2)  
})

module.exports = {
   addEvent: addEvent,
   aFunctionThatUsesAddEvent: aFunctionThatUsesAddEvent  
}
```

**fileB.js**

```
const FileA = require(__dirname + '../fileA');
FileA.addEvent(); // it should work
FileA.aFunctionThatUsesAddEvent() // it should work
```

Answer (score 2):

fileA.js

```
function addEvent(param1, param2) => {
  // do something
})

function aFunctionThatUsesAddEvent(param1, param2) {
  addEvent(param1, param2)
})

module.exports.aFunctionThatUsesAddEvent = aFunctionThatUsesAddEvent
```

FileB.js

```
const FileA = require(__dirname + './fileA'); // Not sure where are you importing the file form

function letsAddEvent(param1, param2) {
   FileA.aFunctionThatUsesAddEvent(param1, param2) {
     // your code
  })
})
```